# Converting DataTable to dynamic class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert data table to smart-table in C#. Basically stored procedure returns dataTable and I need to translate it to JavaScript object, but I don't know what column names I will have. Smart-table is angular-framework which required specific format like below egample:

```
$scope.columnCollection = ["firstName", "lastName", "birthDate", "balance", "email"];

$scope.rowCollection = [
    { firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com' },
    { firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com' },
    { firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com' }
];
```

So I have created this code to translate it:

```
     public class SmartTable
     {
          public IList<string> ColumnCollection { get; set; }
          public IList<Object> RowCollection { get; set; }
     }


        public SmartTable GetTableData(string sp, int widgetId = 0)
    {
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFDbContext"].ConnectionString;
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("exec " + sp, connection))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Mapped);

            IList<string> colColls = new List<string>();

            foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                colColls.Add(dc.Caption);
            }

            IList<Object> rowColls = new List<Object>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                dynamic rowColl = new Object();

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    rowColl.Add(dc.Caption, dr[dc].ToString());
                }
                rowColls.Add(rowColl);

            }

            SmartTable smartTable = new SmartTable
            {
                ColumnCollection = colColls,
                RowCollection = rowColls
            };

        return smartTable;
        };
    }
```

But when I run this I get error "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add'" and the row below is highlighted:

```
rowColl.Add(dc.Caption, dr[dc].ToString());
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

**EDIT**

If I would expect a static data all the time I would do it  like below:

```
public class Row
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string birthDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

but the problem is that I don't know what and how many columns I will have.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Maybe you want `var rowColl = new List<Object>();`. But `List.Add` has no overload that takes two parameters. So i'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Question edited to explain what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
       dynamic rowColl = new Object();

       foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
       {
           rowColl.Add(dc.Caption, dr[dc].ToString());
       }
       rowColls.Add(rowColl);

   }
```

I'm not sure why you're using dynamic -- just use a dictionary, like so:

```
   var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
   foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
   {
       var columnValueList = new List<object>();

       foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
       {
            columnValueList.Add(dataRow[dataColumn.ColumnName]);
       }

       dictionary.Add(dataColumn.ColumnName, columnValueList);
   }
```

Comment: That's not exactly the answer but you gave me the idea how to resolve this, so I will mark it as the answer. If anyone interested with the answer, please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

@returnsvoid answer doesn't give the correct data structure but It gave me the point how to do it. If anyone interested with the exact answer:

```
foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                colColl.Add(dc.Caption);
            }

            IList<Dictionary<string, string>> rowColl = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> row = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(dc.ColumnName, dr[dc].ToString());
                }
                rowColl.Add(row);
            }

            SmartTable smartTable = new SmartTable
            {
                ColumnCollection = colColl,
                RowCollection = rowColl
            };
```